# Why can I print this list from the __init__ but not from a __str__ method

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, oop

I'm trying to create a list that symbolizes a tiled room and each element is initialized to False.  Below is my initialization and I added a print loop at the end so I could make sure it worked.

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        #create a room of size width x height populated with False
        room = [[False for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
        #print statement to verify it worked
        for row in room: print row
```

This produces a nice matrix that looks like a tiled room.  I then tried to write a `__str__` method that would output the object in that same format.

```
def __str__(self):
    for row in self:
        print row
```

I wanted this so I could check the matrix as I was manipulating it, but when I try to do

```
print object
```

I always get

```
TypeError: 'Room' object is not iterable
```

Why will this work in the `__init__` but not in the `__str__` method?  I'm still wrapping my head around OOP.

Answer (score 4):

You should create your variable room as `self.room` in the `__init__` method and later refer to it again as `self.room` in the statement:

```
for row in self.room:
```

Right now your variable `room` remains local to the `__init__` function.

Comment: Not only that, he's trying to loop on `self`... Yes, I'm aware you know that.

Comment: Ok, so to make something available outside of that method I have to have self in front of it (ie self.room)?  That makes sense.  Yeah, I had it looping on self, because I wasn't sure how else to tell it to loop on itself.  I knew self had to be there somewhere.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You also don't want to be printing from `__str__()`.  You want to be returning a string.

Comment: I changed my __init__ to where all the rooms to self.room. I also changed the __str__.  Ultimately trying I'm to get it to print in the format:row\n row\n row\n for a matrix of (x width (columns) and y height(rows). When I do 'for row in self.room: return str(row)' it only prints the first row, whereas if I do 'return self.room' it prints all of it but just a one long list.

Comment: Returning from the inside of your loop obviously will only return once and the iteration will stop at that point. What you want is: creating an empty string, filling in this string from your loop with something like s+=str(row) and then returning this string (after the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't implemented an `__iter__` method on your class. Although you don't need one for what you want to accomplish:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.room = [[False for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
        for row in self.room:
            print row

    def __str__(self):
        for row in self.room:
            print row
```

You can make `self` iterable by implementing an `__iter__()` method on your class:

```
class Room(object):
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for x in self.room:
            yield x
```

Will make your class iterable:

```
>>> r =Room()
>>> r
<__main__.Room instance at 0x02A02620>
>>> for x in r:
        print(x)
0
1
2
3
4
```